# Trigger airflow DAG based on Azure SQL table insert

Tags: mysql, azure, triggers, airflow

Has anyone had a scenario to trigger an airflow DAG based on an insert trigger on a table in azure sql database? I do use logic apps to update a record in the sql db but couldn't find much docs on the vice versa, thanks much

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use [`SQLSensor`](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/_modules/airflow/sensors/sql_sensor.html):

> Runs a sql statement repeatedly until a criteria is met. It will keep
> trying until
> success or failure criteria are met, or if the first cell is not in (0, '0', '', None).

But this doesn exactly fit your purpose, rather than triggering a DAG Run the DAG execution is rather delayed until the criteria is met.

Another option is the usage of the [Airflows experimental REST API](http://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/rest-api-ref.html#post--api-experimental-dags--DAG_ID--dag_runs):

> POST /api/experimental/dags/<DAG_ID>/dag_runs
>
> Creates a dag_run for a given dag id.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, yeah I wanted something to trigger the DAGs dynamically as and when there is an update on the Azure SQL DB, I did stumble upon the airflow rest post call, but think I might need a listener on the azure SQL DB to listen to changes on that table and trigger the airflow post command